# What does "curse of love" mean?

Tags: meaning

Alexie finds his wife commiting adultery:

> Alexei: I will not return to this house until divorce has driven you into the street.
> Meanwhile, my son will be sent to live with my eldest sister. Do you think
> I would let you have my son? You are depraved. A woman without honor.
> I thank God the **curse of love** is lifted from me.

What does "curse of love" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this quote, Alexei is saying that he used to have love, but no longer has love.  He is also calling love, itself, a curse.  "The curse of love" means that I have been cursed, and the curse is love.

Love is not usually considered a curse, but those who "have loved and lost", as the poets say, feel a lot of pain when love is broken.  Love can leave you vulnerable, love can cause you to make poor decisions.  Many people have written about the downsides to love.  For any of these downsides, Alexei considers love to be a curse.

Be aware of the usage of the word "curse".  The two most common verbs associated with any curse are to "lay a curse on ", to cause someone to become curse, and to "lift a curse on ", to cause someone to no longer be cursed.

Comment: I think it may be just the curse of loving his wife, rather than all forms of love.